# Stacking order and position fixed

Tags: html, css

Shortly, here's my problem:

[f http://d.pr/i/Kge6+](http://d.pr/i/Kge6+)

There's three images positioned absolutely in a box that's in position fixed. I'd like the illustrations not to pass on top, but I've tried a lot of things (changing z-index, removing them..)

But it didn't work.

```
<section class="home">
    <container>
        <div class="center-homepage">
            <img src="img/home-mascot.svg" alt="" class="mascot">
            <img src="img/home-scribble.svg" alt="" class="scribble">
            <img src="img/home-circles.svg" alt="" class="circles">
        </div>
    </container>
</section>
<section class="content">
    <div class="container">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa, quisquam, excepturi, debitis, accusamus harum consequatur expedita consequuntur pariatur quae autem unde molestiae laboriosam repudiandae iste illum quasi possimus placeat reiciendis?
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, et, totam, magni, fugiat nesciunt qui quas tempore atque consequuntur ad neque eum ex modi beatae error necessitatibus officia fuga odio.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem, voluptatibus, itaque sed saepe exercitationem atque voluptas! Similique, temporibus, fugit, tempora, voluptate culpa asperiores eligendi quibusdam explicabo repellendus esse quasi earum?</p>
    </div>
</section>

.home {
  height: 576px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: url(' (a lot of data URI) ') no-repeat center 32px, #8b737a;
  background-attachment: fixed; }

.center-homepage {
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: -250px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 90px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1; }
```

And the css:

```
.mascot, .circles, .scribble {
  position: absolute; }

.mascot {
  width: 190px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -95px;
  top: 60px;
  z-index: 5; }

.circles {
  width: 230px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -123px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 0; }

.scribble {
  width: 400px;
  top: 160px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  z-index: 3; }

.content {
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative; }
```

[here's the live website](http://aurelieremia.be/tfa/)

I do not get the "stacking order context" too well. From what I've got, if the parent have a bigger z-index, it will be more important than all its children, but apparently it's not that.

Comment: It doesn't look like your image is passing over the text. Just give the text a background color and you'll see the text is on top. Or do you mean the content section that contains the text container?

Comment: @DavidGraham Yes, I mean the text container :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems all you need is:

```
.content {background: white;}
```

... unless I'm missing something.

Comment: ... I've been trying to fix it for more than 1 hour. Thank you, I feel silly, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a white div that has a z-index above the fixed picture that contains the text, instead of just a background. Or, you could try giving the fixed images a negative z-index.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to keep the code the cleanest I can, not adding markup to fix bugs. I did tried that, but, strangely, it didn't change much.